# Who/which system has read a message from Azure Service bus Queue

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a way to watch who exactly/Which system has read a message from Azure Service bus Queue ? 
through a log or any other tool ?
showing a url or IP or Name

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Server side logging is a requested feature, but currently not available.